# Matplotlib: create a blank plot with a specific background color?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a blank plot figure of a specific background color and then plot some points on it. The background color could be white, but I would like gray with RGB values `200, 200, 200`.

In the code below, I create a 3-D Numpy matrix `M` and then set the values on the 3rd axis to the color values `200, 200, 200`. However, the plot comes out with a white background:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

M = np.zeros(shape=(960, 1280, 3))
M[:, :,] = np.array([200, 200, 200]) # Arbitrary RGB color - I chose gray

print(M.shape) # Prints: (960, 1280, 3)

_ = plt.imshow(M)

for point in [[200, 200], [1200, 600], [1200, 800], [200, 400]]:

    x = point[0]
    y = point[1]
    _ = plt.plot(x, y, marker='o', markersize=5)

_ = plt.grid()
_ = plt.show()
```

When I run the code, I see the following message

```txt
Clipping input data to the valid range for imshow with RGB data ([0..1]
for floats or [0..255] for integers).
```

and the figure has a white background.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When you create the initial matrix, you need to set `dtype=np.unint8`. If you leave that out, then the type will be `float64`, thereby bringing up the error that you stated:

```txt
Clipping input data to the valid range for imshow with RGB data ([0..1]
for floats or [0..255] for integers).
```

Float values need to be in the range 0.0 to 1.0.

The easy fix is to provide the `dtype` when you create the matrix:

```py
M = np.zeros(shape=(960, 1280, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
```

Here is the result with the desired gray color:

[image]